# Using PHP with Lightttpd on a 128MB RAM Server

Tags: php, memory-management, lighttpd

I am building a small web interface to a database that will run on a Pogoplug Pro (128MB RAM).  The app is unlikely to ever have more than four or five simultaneous users, and will run with sqlite as the database backend.  Is it feasible to use a Lightttpd - PHP combination (with fastcgi) on this system?  For other reasons enabling swap is not an option.  Or should I try to use more lightweight languages such as Python?

Comment: 128MB is pretty borderline to even get the underlying OS up and running these days. I guess all you can do is try, besides anecdotal evidence there's hardly a clear answer.

Comment: True.  The OS is running fine - Debian Squeeze - but is using about 40MB.  But do other languages - Python for instance - use significantly less memory?  I understand PHP is a memory hog, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Java frameworks, and various other languages running on the JVM, take significantly more memory (I'd expect a minimum server size of 512MB, at a guess). I've gotten LAMP to run in a 256MB server with no modifications at all, however.

Comment: Take a look at this too, interesting: http://www.lowendtalk.com/wiki/

Comment: That's a very useful page, halfer - if this was an answer and not a comment I would have voted you up :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP is indeed a memory hog as it allocates memory for all the different types of c variable (int, float, string, boolean etc) for every single variable you declare ([Source](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/)). I'm not sure about the memory footprints of other languages. But I would suggest looking into HipHop for PHP.

Hiphop is an open source project released by Facebook a couple of years ago that compiles PHP code into highly optimised C++ that runs directly on the underlying OS. Once you hit compile, you get a full web stack with your PHP application bundled into it that runs fast and uses less memory. You can find hiphop at GitHub [here](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/). I'm not sure how mature it is, but it's certainly a possibility for your situation :)

Just so you know, I don't work for facebook or hiphop, I just think its a really clever system :)

Comment: Given that there is 80MB of free memory according to the comments on the question, that's ample for a random php script. Hiphop might be viable but it's hardly designed for the use case of this question, and makes no claims regarding reducing memory - which is the pinch point here.

Comment: Thanks AD7six - so I gather you think there should be no problem with this system?  I know no one can give guarantees, but that would at least mean I can go ahead with design in PHP rather than trying to use something else.

Comment: Hiphop does claim to reduce memory - that was one of the design specifications from the talk in my first link. PHP allocates lots of memory per variable baring in mind you don't need to tell it what type your variable is so it could be anything. Hiphop infers the type of your variables and allocates only the necessary space. I'm having trouble finding any direct comparison benchmarks, but memory usage is certainly improved.

Comment: Are you referring to this: *"We also use type inference to pick the most specific type possible for our variables"*? I don't think that means that PHP is *"allocating memory for all the different types of c variable for every single variable you declare"*. That would be really nonsensical. I think it just means that, for instance, PHP only has one type of int, whereas C has several integer types, some of which may be more efficient in any given situation.

Comment: Well its not quite every single type. PHP stores your variable in a c union type so the variable's maximum size will always be the largest of the types in said union - I think that's double if I recall correctly (since a string would be stored as a pointer to a char array and pointers are 32 or 64 bit memory blocks). HipHop is able to infer the difference between a string, an int/long and a float/double thereby saving a few bits per variable. Perhaps not such a huge saving in a small program, but if you're working with lots of data, then the saving is certainly not negligible.